# Android WindowManager changing screen orientation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-windowmanager, android-layoutparams

Im adding a camera overlay with WindowManager to a running Activity. When I start the camera and call for the WindowManager, it changes my screen from portrait to landscape, even though I assigned the appropriate portrait tag to the WindowManager.LayoutParams. Haven't been able to find any solutions via google.

Here is my WindowManager code running in a method in a service:

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(mContext.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    View view;

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.camera, null, false);

    p = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    p.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
    p.screenOrientation = ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT;

    windowManager.addView(view,p);
```

The layout R.layout.camera is just a FrameLayout view that I add my camera to. Camera is working fine. My activity running underneath is portrait (As it should be) until the WindowManager instance turns it back to landscape. And yes, I have the portrait tag in my Manifest.

Edit: With further investigation, the windowmanager is destroying and recreating my activity running, and this is causing everything to revert to landscape mode. I even tried setting the orientation dynamically in the onCreate of the Activity, but that did not work either. When I stop the service with all of the above windowmanager code, my activity goes back to portrait mode.

Comment: did you find any solution, I'm facing same problem.

Answer (score -2):

```
      android:screenOrientation="portrait"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
```

Try defining this in your manifest under activity.

Comment: I already had the screen Orientation tag, added the configChanges and that did not help